# Excluding integration tests in yaml not working

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, cicd, vstest

I am trying to have two tasks for executing the integration tests:

1. With external dependencies; and
2. Without

Project names: My.Web.App.Sps and My.Web.Ap.Tests.Integration
They are getting published in the following location:

tests/My.Web.App/My.Web.App.Sps/bin/Release/net48/
tests/My.Web.App/My.Web.Ap.Tests.Integration/bin/Release/net48/

```
- download: current
  artifact: tests

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run int tests (without dependency)'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*test*.dll
     **\*sps.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=IntegrationTest&TestCategory=${{ parameters.testEnvironment }}&TestCategory!=ExternalDependency'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runInParallel: false
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    testRunTitle: 'Integration Tests without dependencies'
```

The other task is obviously without the ! sign in front of External dependency

I have tried to have sps and integration test separately but it passes without executing any tests.

If, however, I remove external dependency completely and have only the following filter:

```
'TestCategory=IntegrationTest&TestCategory=${{ parameters.testEnvironment }}'
```

It executes some tests but not all obviously.

Comment: Did you check the output files when building the test project?

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT Thank you for your response! I am sorry but what exactly would you want me to check?

Comment: Check whether the wildcard patterns can match the output files?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Meanwhile I was trying a bit and saw something that I missed earlier. It was the search folder missing. I forced it to searchFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/tests/My.Web.App' and this worked

Comment: I will post as answer

Comment: If possible, you might post an answer with more details about how you resolve the issue.  This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use searchFolder param

```
- download: current
  artifact: tests

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run int tests (without dependency)'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*test*.dll
     **\*sps.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=IntegrationTest&TestCategory=${{ parameters.testEnvironment }}&TestCategory!=ExternalDependency'
    searchFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/tests/My.Web.App'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runInParallel: false
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    testRunTitle: 'Integration Tests without dependencies'
```